# mouseout image hide div containing text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following script that shows/hides some text when an image is clicked. This text then is replaced when another image is clicked and so on. At the moment there is always some text visible.
I want this text to disappear (or perhaps display and empty div?) on mouseOut of the image.
Here is what I currently have:

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<!--
function showonlyonev2(thechosenone) {
    var newboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
      for(var x=0; x<newboxes.length; x++) {
          name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("name");
          if (name == 'textboxes') {
              if (newboxes[x].id == thechosenone) {
                  if (newboxes[x].style.display == 'block') {

                  } else {
                      newboxes[x].style.display = 'block';
                  }
              } else {
                  newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
              }
          }
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="text-container">
  <div id="text1" name="textboxes">
  <p>Some text here about person 1</p>
  <div id="text2" name="textboxes">
  <p>Some text here about person 2</p>
  <div id="text3" name="textboxes">
  <p>Some text here about person 3</p>
  <div id="text4" name="textboxes">
  <p>Some text here about person 4</p>
</div>


<div class="people-images">
  <a href="javascript:showonlyonev2('text1');" class="rollovers">
    <div id="person1-rollover"><img src="images/people/person1.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="people-images">
  <a href="javascript:showonlyonev2('text2');" class="rollovers">
    <div id="person2-rollover"><img src="images/people/person2.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="people-images">
  <a href="javascript:showonlyonev2('text3');" class="rollovers">
    <div id="person3-rollover"><img src="images/people/person3.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="people-images">
  <a href="javascript:showonlyonev2('text4');" class="rollovers">
    <div id="person4-rollover"><img src="images/people/person4.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#text1 { 
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: #c2bfba;
}
#text2, #text3, #text4 { 
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: #c2bfba;
display:none; 
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this in the image tag:

```
   <img src='...' onmouseover='javascript:showonlyonev2('text1')' onmouseout='javascript:showonlyonev2('blank')' />
```

This way your function gets called whenever the image is hovered over. you can create an empty div called 'blank' so that your function uses it when mouse out, so it appears blank.

Keep your Javascript the same.

Change your HTML to:

```
<div id="text-container">
<!-- All of these DIV's should have closing tags -->
<div id="text1" name="textboxes"><p>Some text here about person 1</p></div>
<div id="text2" name="textboxes"><p>Some text here about person 2</p></div>
<div id="text3" name="textboxes"><p>Some text here about person 3</p></div>
<div id="text4" name="textboxes"><p>Some text here about person 4</p></div>
<div id="blank" name="textboxes"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
</div>


<div class="people-images">
<a href="javascript:showonlyonev2('text1');" class="rollovers">
<div id="person1-rollover"><img src="images/people/person1.jpg" onmouseout="javascript:showonlyonev2('blank');" alt="" /> </div></a>
</div>
<div class="people-images">
<a href="javascript:showonlyonev2('text2');" class="rollovers">
<div id="person2-rollover"><img src="images/people/person2.jpg" onmouseout="javascript:showonlyonev2('blank');" alt="" /> </div></a>
</div>
<div class="people-images">
<a href="javascript:showonlyonev2('text3');" class="rollovers">
<div id="person3-rollover"><img src="images/people/person3.jpg" onmouseout="javascript:showonlyonev2('blank');" alt="" /> </div></a>
</div>
<div class="people-images">
<a href="javascript:showonlyonev2('text4');" class="rollovers">
<div id="person4-rollover"><img src="images/people/person4.jpg"  onmouseout="javascript:showonlyonev2('blank');" alt="" /> </div></a>
</div>
```

Change your CSS to:

```
#blank { 
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: #c2bfba;
}
#text1, #text2, #text3, #text4 { 
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: #c2bfba;
display:none; 
}
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately I need the link as this changes the image that is clicked. So the image changes AND the text. Thanks!

Comment: My bad, I should have realized that. My solution doesn't **require** you to remove the link, I just didn't think you would still need it.

Comment: No worries - just trying to think of a way of combining them, thanks again for your help!

Comment: There you go! I rewrote it, so all your links stay the same, and it just changes the text when the mouse moves over it, and an empty div when no images has a mouse over it.

Comment: Fantastic - almost there, but when the image is clicked I don't want the text to disappear, only onmouseout. Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, so just to make sure I understand you completely, if the user clicks the image, you want the text to stay even on mouse out? the text should just disappear if the user hasn't clicked the image? At least, for me right now, the text doesn't disappear onclick, only on mouseout.

Comment: The text only changes if you click the image. When you mouseout of the image the text for that image disappears and is replaced with the blank div. When you click on the next image the text for that image appears and so on - does that make sense?

Comment: Ah! gotcha. That's a quick fix, I'll remove the onmouseover event handlers in the image and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks Sam, thats sorted the mouseover from showing the text but its still disappearing onclick!

Comment: That does work, but the issue I'm having is because I remove the image when its clicked (to display one underneath) and this triggers the mouseout event! Can we add this to the containing div rather than the image?

Comment: Yeah, just take the **onmouseout="javascript:showonlyonev2('blank');"** line out of the image, and put it into the div you want.